# Error accessing build artifacts hosted on S3 maven repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven, gradle, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch my artifacts from my private S3 bucket. When I attempt to build, I get the following error on my terminal.

```
Could not find aop-logging-0.0.1.jar (np.com.oskarshrestha:aop-logging:0.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    s3://<my-bucket-name>/release/np/com/oskarshrestha/aop-logging/0.0.1/aop-logging-0.0.1.jar
```

Things I have verified:

✔ The object exists in S3 bucket with correct path

✔ The policy used by IAM user

✔ Using correct accessKey and secretKey

Following is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "s3://<my-bucket-name>/release"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
            secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
        }
    }
}

group = 'np.com.oskarshrestha'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'book-store-backend'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

dependencies {
    < ! -- removed other dependencies ->
    implementation 'np.com.oskarshrestha:aop-logging:0.0.1'
}
```

Following is my user policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<-my-bucket-name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<-my-bucket-name->/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: WHy not use the AWS Official Java V2 API (as opposed to 3rd party).  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html